# Reading a txt file, and putting each word into an array, without punctuation or numbers

Tags: java

I am wondering how I would read a txt file with Java, and put each word from the txt file into a different bucket in an array, but without punctuation or numbers that are in the file. I'm only interested in storing the words.

So if the text file contained: "25 chickens crossed the road." the program should create an array like {"chickens", "crossed", "the", "road"}

<strike>I would like to do this on a fairly large text file. Will I run into any run time issues?</strike>

If you could explain it to me like I'm a complete noob, that would be great.
I appreciate it.

Comment: This is a bit vague, whether or not you encounter run-time issues will depend on your implementation. And SO questions should usually be about specific implementations. (If you're asking about how to best implement it we'll need more details about your project)

Answer (score 0):

Do a `.replaceAll(regex, "")` which will replace all matching characters with the contents of the second parameter (an empty string in this case). Matching is done with a regular expression.

Second step is to use `.split(regex)` on your returned string from `replaceAll`, and split the string on space ( `.split(" ")` ). This will return an array with all the words separate.

An easy way to write regular expressions is to use http://www.regexr.com

**Example code:** (not tested)

```
String oldText = "25 chickens crossed the road.";

String newText = oldText.replaceAll("\!|\.|\?|\d/g","");

String[] strArray = newText.split(" ","");
```